# Can a stochastic optimization in place of deterministic optimization help us dealing with small sample data set?

Tags: optimization, small-sample

So there is a radioactive point source and it is traversing at constant velocity though a medium. It emits two gamma at same time (called annihilation gamma of energy 511 keV). Detector detects two gamma rays and that defines the a line. Right now I have 10000 such lines and I am trying to find the path through which source traversed. Optimization problem is about minimising the perpendicular distance from the traversed path to those line (see figure).

[image]

Now, about small data what happens is, when activity of the source is small then we have small number those lines, let's say in place of 10000 we have 1000 or even 100. Do you think stochastic optimization will help in this small number of lines case? You see, those lines are not exact. Detector always going to have some error. I am wondering whether a stochastic formulation can give us more accurate track or not.

Please forgive me if it is silly question. I am not an expert in this field.

Also I am open for any different kind of suggestion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How small is "small"?  What exactly is the optimization problem?  Would would constitute a "better" result?

Comment: Ok, so there is a radioactive point source and it is traversing at constant velocity though a medium. It emits two gamma at same time (called annihilation gamma of energy 511 keV).  Detector detects two gamma rays and that defines the a line. Right now I have 10000 such line and I am trying to find the path through which source traversed. Optimization problem is about minimising the perpendicular distance from the traversed path to those line.

Comment: Now, about small data what happens is, when activity of the source is small then we have small number those line, let's say in place of 10000 we have 1000 or even 100. Do you think stochastic optimization will help in this small number of lines case? You see, those lines are not exact. Detector always going to have some error. I am wondering whether a stochastic formulation can give us more accurate track or not. Thanks for your interest. Cheers.

Comment: Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: One suggestion: incorporate information from the comments into the post.  Comments don't get the same attention as the post itself.

Comment: Sure. I have edited the question. Thank you @whuber

Comment: I have edited the question. Looking forward to your comment. Thank you